# Issue with Request.IsAuthenticated after Login page mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, authentication, forms-authentication

I am having an issue with checking the authentication when a user logs in to my site.  So  I have a login page (Login.cshtml), that of course a user would login from.  From there the user would be sent to an index page. My issue is that when i hit this

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
}
else
{
    <strong>Something went wrong</strong>
}
```

it fails into the else statement and writes something went wrong.  Any advice on how to combat this error would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <strong>@Html.Encode(User.Identity.Name)</strong>
}
else
{
    <strong>Something went wrong</strong>
}
```

My UserContoller(has all the methods for the login):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var user = db.User.Include(u => u.UserName);
            var loggedInUser = User.Identity.Name;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (isValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "User Name or Password is incorrect");
                }
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        private bool isValid(string UserName, string Password)
        {
            bool isValid = false;

            //var user = db.User.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == UserName);
            var user = db.User.Where(u => u.UserName == UserName).FirstOrDefault();
            var pass = db.User.Where(u => u.Password == Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null && pass != null)
            {
                isValid = true;
            }

            return isValid;
        }
```

Comment: Have you had a look at this question here ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933430/request-isauthenticated-return-false-all-the-time

Comment: I added this to my web.config file <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Login.cshtml"
             protection="All"
             timeout="30"
             name=".ASPXAUTH"
             path="/"
             requireSSL="false"
             slidingExpiration="true"
             defaultUrl="default.aspx"
             cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
             enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
    </authentication>... I am stil getting the same error.  How do I find the path and defaulturl?