# How to get whether user is authenticated by custom Action Filter in ASP.NET MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an action method that uses my authentication filter:

```
public class TutorAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
        {
            var cred = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = cred[0], Password = cred[1] };
            if (userService.AuthorizeTutor(user.Name, user.Password))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", $"Basic realm= {BasicRealm}");

        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

I would like to then display on main page something for user that have been authenticated this way, but this does not work in my View :(

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <h1>Hello</h1>
}
```

I know it does not work because I don't use Identity, but is there any way that I can do this?

Thank you for answers :)

Comment: From where `userService` came from? Does it have some property which can retururns authenticated state?

Comment: DI, I just omitted some not important properties... it just returns true/false

Comment: that filter automatically stores some data into cookies so there is authenticated state stored

Comment: do you have mind if the solution used 'Identity' ??

Comment: Yes I would like the solution without Identity

Comment: When you say you would like a solution without Identity, does that also leaves out the possibility of setting Thread.CurrentPrincipal to a GenericPrincipal?

Comment: How about using `Session` or `var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag; viewbag.IsAuthenticated = true` and then accessing this in view?

Comment: Kamolas81 is right - setting that property will make Request.IsAuthenticated work the way you want

Comment: @Kamolas81 how does that work? can you give me some example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose, that sending login and password in header is not secure. Better solution is one time when user is verified. And after checking, you can check all request.

For example, if you use `FormsAuthentication` and authCookie it's very simple:

1. Set auth mentod in web.config: `<authentication mode="Forms" />`
2. When login and password is valid, use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie = true);` This step is performed only once, when user login to application.
3. Then you can use property `this.Request.IsAuthenticated` in view or `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated` in controller (or filter).
4. And it works attribute `[Authorize]` on conntrolers or actions (public methods in conntrollers). When request is not authenticated, request is redirected to default (or set in web.config) login page.

Comment: I don't think that sending login and password in header is not secure (when you use HTTPS). I will try to check some documents about FormsAuthentication if it solves my problem :)

Comment: This works very nice, but I found an article about that FormsAuthentication is obsolete because it does not run on Owin (which doesn't matter in my case)

Answer (score 4):

Create a new extension method for the request object say (IsUserAuthenticated()) & in that method check if the user is valid. 
Once this is done, you can use this new extension method the same way you are using Request.IsAuthenticated Property.

Below is the sample code, which you will need to tweak as per your needs. (specifically for

```
userservice
```

initialization)

```
public class RequestValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(HttpRequest request)
    {
       bool isValid  = false;

       //TODO: Intitialize your userService here, may be using DI or a concrete object creation depending on your implementation

       var auth = request.Headers["Authorization"];
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
       {
           var cred = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(auth.Substring(6))).Split(':');
           var user = new { Name = cred[0], Password = cred[1] };

           isValid = userService.AuthorizeTutor(user.Name, user.Password))            
       }

      return isValid; 
    }
}
```

Your attribute will change like this

```
public class TutorAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator(); 
        if(validator.IsValid(request))
        {
            return; 
        }

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", $"Basic realm= {BasicRealm}");

        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

And the extension method to be used on view will be

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsUserAuthenticated(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        RequestValidator validator = new RequestValidator(); 
        return validator.IsValid(request); 
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
@if(Request.IsUserAuthenticated())
{
     <p>Hello</p>
}
```

Comment: But how can I check, if the user is valid?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not work properly. Hello is only displayed on pages that demand authentization - I need to display it even on other pages after the user typed correct username and password. ( I have a feeling maybe I need to somehow access cookies that it indirectly uses?)

Comment: You can replace the authorization code with cookies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the boolean value indicating if the user is authenticated,  maybe it makes sense to just use the model object and pass it to the view.

Or maybe you should review your Form Authentication to make `Request.IsAuthenticated` working properly. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933430/request-isauthenticated-return-false-all-the-time) will help to start digging.

Another option would be to consider using the IAuthorizationFilter instead of the custom action filter. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708942/should-i-be-using-an-iauthorizationfilter-if-i-wish-to-create-an-apikey-restrict) will be a starting point.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I used second option (as suggested by ksciana before), I don't think that other options will solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

To meet your purpose, you would need to set `HttpContext.User` to some valid IPrincipal.
So, if according to your criteria, the user is valid you just need to create a `GenericPrinicpal` and set `HttpContext.User` with the instance you have just created.

Something like this:

```
var genericIdentity=new GenericIdentity(user.Name,  "CustomAuthType");
var genericPrincipal=new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, null);

HttpContext.User = genericPrincipal;
```

With `GenericIdentity`, the value of `IsAuthenticated` is dependent on the Name property, so as soon as the `GenericIdentity` has a Name, it is considered to be authenticated.

In this example, I'm setting the `HttpContext.User` and not the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` so that you can get the `IsAuthenticated` from the `Request.IsAuthenticated` property.

Some extra and related information:

[GenericIdentity Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Principal and Identity Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftx85f8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Create GenericPrincipal and GenericIdentity Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9dd5fx0.aspx)

[Replacing a Principal Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2zhxceh.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for interesting answer, I will look into it more and let everyone know if and how it solves the problem :) Unfortunately I won't have enough time to award you the bounty because it ends tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

in your startup.cs file add this

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),

            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40)


        });
```

Comment: Thanks, but just this won't work with my custom authentication